# How to set height in RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager and dynamic child heights?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

First to be clear, I already have this working pretty well, I'm here just to ask if there is a "better way", and what's generally the "best practice" for this, because I have very minor stuttering during scroll, which I think is due to constantly changing child height, so it would be best if somebody from Google could answer this, or somebody completely sure of what the best practice is.

On to the point. Currently, I set heights this way:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.image.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;

}
```

Every child has individual "newHeight" which is calculated from image aspect ratio.

It works fine, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch the image, save its bounds so that next time when you need to show the same image, items will not move around.

Also, if you own the backend API that sends you image information, send the metadata (image w/h) in your API response so that you can set placeholders to the correct size.

Comment: Yeah I already have the metadata thing, but I've been doing some further research, by completely removing height changes, I've even switched to normal GridLayoutManager just to try it.. And the micro stutter is still there.. So it seems that heights are not the problem as I thought, it must be something with RecyclerView itself, because I've also used normal GridView before it, and that worked perfectly smooth. Another interesting thing is that not all phones have that stutter.. It's visible just on a few phones, including my Nexus 4.

Comment: Can you override onFailedToRecycle in your ViewHolder ? RecyclerView may be failing to recycle views because of transient state (potentially fade in animation when image arrives ?). It is very easy to recover by the application but we cannot auto-recover from that state w/o potential bugs. See the documentation for details.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onFailedToRecycleView(VH)

Comment: I tried that and views are recycling fine.. I might be just overreacting, although I'm sure that GridView worked better.. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: what do you mean by save its bounds ? Could you provide a code sample please ?